# editor font zoom config value not in setting.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set `editor font zoom in/out`, but the set value are not been written in my vscode setting.json.
[image]

There does have `"window.zoomLevel": 1.5` in my setting.json, but it's not `Editor Font Zoom`'s value, its the whole View's zoom level.

My question is why the config `editor font zoom in/out` is not showing in my setting.json config file.

Comment: some related source code in [src/vs/editor/contrib/fontZoom/browser/fontZoom.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/fontZoom/browser/fontZoom.ts), possibly [src/vs/editor/common/config/editorZoom.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/common/config/editorZoom.ts), and [src/vs/editor/browser/config/editorConfiguration.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/browser/config/editorConfiguration.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Zooming the font doesn't affect settings because there isn't a setting for Editor Font Zoom level.

If you want to change the editor's font size, use the **Font Size** setting:

[image: VSCode Font Size setting]